# Adding linker options to Code::Blocks

Tags: c++, linker, codeblocks, libgcc

When i try to run an executable compiled with Code::Blocks on my Win 7 x64 machine, it says it cannot run because the libgcc_s_dw2-1 is missing.

I found a solution, to include the library in the linker options. (here is the reference i got it from:  http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=16748.0;prev_next=prev. look at the last post)

The thing is, when i go to the linker settings, in Project Build Options, there are no libraries available there. Do i have to download the

```
-static-libgcc
-static-libstdc++
```

as stated by the post, and put them in a directory so Code::Blocks can see them and add them to the linker options? If yes, where do i put the libraries?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Never mind, i found the answer in this post
http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,15998.0.html

To sum up, in Code Blocks, go to

```
"Settings" -> "Compiler and debugger..."
"Global compiler settings"
"Linker settings"
```

Then add the following options to `"Other linker options":

```
-static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Then you are off to go...